# Issue while reading a file from WAR file

Tags: java

I have a war file with the below structure.

```
--js
  --sum.js
--WEB-INF
  --classes
    ---com
       -----test
           -----MyTest.class
--home.html
```

I am trying to read the js file in my MyTest.class file,But I am getting exception while reading it. I tried most of the solutions already mentioned in the stack.

I have tried

1)

```
String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("js/sum.js").getPath();
        File f = new File(path);
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

First line is throwing nullpointer exception

2)

```
InputStream in =MyNashHornTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/js/sum.js");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Second line is throwing null pointer exception

3)

```
InputStream in =MyNashHornTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../../../../js/sum.js");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Second line is throwing null pointer exception

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For war files, don’t use the servlet container’s classloader, but use the ServletContext instead.

This method allows servlet containers to make a resource available to a servlet from any location, without using a class loader.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/yourfilename.txt");
```

It is recommended to keep it under the /WEB-INF directory if you don’t want browers being able to access it.

The path must begin with a `« / »` and is interpreted as relative to the current context root. This method returns null if no resource exists at the specified path. For example `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(« WEB-INF/resources/yourfilename.cnf »)` will return a nul exception, so be careful !

### Why null pointer comes??

The path must begin with a "/" and is interpreted as relative to the current context root. This method returns null if no resource exists at the specified path. For example, using a path that doesn't start with a slash, You will get a null return value.

Details Description is given here: [How to use ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String path)?](http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/how-to-use-servletcontextgetresourceasstreamjavalangstring-path/18)

### Resource Link:

[HOW TO: Read a file from jar and war files (java and webapp archive) ?](https://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-and-war-files-java-and-webapp-archive/)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have modified it.

Comment: @SkyWalker is there any other way of getting servlet context other than extending the httpservlet.

Comment: @robin: Of course, but this one is the more common. You can also implement a ContextLoaderListener to store the ServletContext in a static variable (because a simple webapp contains one single ServletContext). You could also use a Filter implementation, or simply use the `init` method of a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get resources from the class path with `ClassLoader.getResource` or from the web root directory with `ServletContext.getResource`.

In a war, you use the former to access ressources stored under `WEB-INF/classes`, or in jars under `WEB-INF/lib`, and the former for what lies directly at the root of the web application.